# custom ThreadPoolExecutor with delays

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, threadpool

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor to throttle call to my servlet, I referred to my below link:
http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/blogs/2010/08/13/asynchronous-servlets-in-servlet-spec-3-0/

This gives great example. But need add delays. How do it here.
I am maintaining a pool of 7 threads, which run simultaneously. But new threads should creted from queue after all threads get complete and i need put before that.
so every 7 calls, i need a delay before more threads are pooled from queue and runned as task.

Will ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor help, if so how. Or how can modify the existing ThreadPoolExecutor will help.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to throttle servlet requests, asynchronous requests with a thread pool is *not* the way to solve the problem.  the easiest way is to add a Filter which limits the incoming requests using something like a semaphore.

if you need to use asynchronous requests and want the throttle them, then just use a limited size thread pool.

Comment: I had tried that, Even had a working code, it was based on sync model not, Async model. Can you help me convert it. More the code used jetty contuanation. I need a tomcat implentation.

Comment: [link](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty/trunk/jetty-servlets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/QoSFilter.java)

Comment: please suggest some solution?